# ReactJs unable to get react-rout params.It gives undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i want get ssisionValue on todoapp. which i passed from login.jsx.
and want this value in todoapp.jsx.but by using **this.props.params** returns undefined.
app.jsx

```
 ReactDOM.render(
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Main}>
            <Route path="RegistrationForm" component={RegistrationForm}/>
            <Route path="todoapp/:sessionValue" component={TodoApp}/>
            <IndexRoute component={Login}/>
        </Route>
      </Router>, 
      document.getElementById('app')
    );
```

login.jsx

```
axios.post('/login', {
                    email:this.state.strEmail,
                    password:this.state.strPassword
                    })
                    .then(function (response) {
                    //console.log(response.data);
                    var sessionValue=response.data;
                    browserHistory.push('/todoapp/sessionValue');
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
```

todoapp.jsx

```
render:function(){
        var {urlValue}=this.props.params.sessionValue;//it returns undefined
        alert(urlValue);
        var {todos}=this.state;
        return(
            <div>
                Todoapp
                <TodoSearch onSearch={this.handleSearch}/>
                <TodoList todos={todos} onToggle={this.handleToggle}/>
                <AddTodo onAddTodo={this.handleAddTodo}/>
            </div>
            )
    }
});
```

I get the following object with params

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the thing is that you are using destructing but for the wrong reason. In

```
var {urlValue}=this.props.params.sessionValue;
```

you are actually trying to get the urlValue from the object `this.props.params.sessionValue`. There are few things your can do

```
1. var {sessionValue as urlValue} = this.props.params,
2. var {sessionValue} = this.props.params
3. var urlValue = this.props.params.sessionValue
```

Also in your login.jsx file you need to route like

```
browserHistory.push(`/todoApp/${sessionValue}`)
```

Comment: it return its variable name i.e. sessionValue. not the value which is assgin to sessionValue

Comment: which method do you follow, also check what do you get when you do console.log(this.props)

Comment: it returns params:object

Comment: Can your attach the screen shot of the object after expanding it. I think the above answer shouldhave worked

Comment: Are you calling the url as `http://localhost:8080/todoapp/sessionValue` or `http://localhost:8080/todoapp/1`

Comment: where??in login.jsx i am using browser.push('todo/sessionValue');axios.post('/login', {
                    email:this.state.strEmail,
                    password:this.state.strPassword
                    })
                    .then(function (response) {
                    //console.log(response.data);
                    var sessionValue=response.data;
                    browserHistory.push('/todoapp/sessionValue');
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });

Comment: exactly since you are calling the router like /todo/sessionValue, you are getting the params as `sessionValue`. If in your login.jsx, sessionValue is dynamic variable then you can do it like `browserHistory.push(\`todo/${sessionValue}\`);`

Comment: then it gives me this error.  Warning: [react-router] Location "todo/vaishnavi" did not match any routes does not redirect.should we need to change in app.jsx routing path

Comment: It should be `browserHistory.push(\`/todoApp/${sessionValue}\`)`

Comment: when i use browserHistory.push(`todo/${sessionValue}`); In url it gives sessionValue.but does not redirect and trows the above mention error

Comment: sory..thank you so much for helping me thruout.I am new to reactJs

Answer (score 0):

Remove `{}`, use this:

```
var urlValue = this.props.params.sessionValue;
alert(urlValue);
```

Or use it like this with `{}`:

```
var {sessionValue} = this.props.params;
alert(sessionValue);
```

Check the [DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: it return its variable name i.e. sessionValue. not the value which is assgin to sessionValue.

Comment: can you show the result of `console.log(this.props)` ?

Comment: @vaishnaviaher image that you attached, shows that name and value are same : `{'sessionValue': 'sessionValue'}` thats why.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using React Router v4, try

```
this.props.match.params.sessionValue
```

Comment: He is using IndexRoute and browserHistory, so I think he is not using react-router version 4